# VMWare equivalent

Tags: vmware

I need to do testing on clean machines frequently so I need some kind of virtual machine emulator which can load and run clean OS images.
Do you know any recommended freeware or low cost emulator?

Comment: See (Relatively) recent thread on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032305/vmware-equivalent

Comment: Even though I now prefer Virtual Box for network testing, VMWare was open source up until version 7.  You can still download version 6 here, which uses an open source license.  They decided to require a commercial license at version 7.  You can usually take an old image and get the config file and replace a later version's config file to make a new image (for v7 or later) compatible with v6.  https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-607|product_downloads

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been using VirtualBox for a while - http://www.virtualbox.org/ - and it works a treat

Comment: Only VirtualBox OSE is actually 'free'

Comment: +1 VirtualBox works great. Note, however, that the open-source version does not virtualize USB controllers. And the closed source version is available for free, but only for testing purposes.

Comment: @Aiden and @balpha - Reread the license agreement and in particular the license FAQ.  The commercial version is available for "personal use" at no charge, where "personal use" means you install it and use it yourself (even if it's for work).

Comment: I had a concern re "personal use" but the FAQ sets it out clearly: Personal use is when you install the product on one or more PCs yourself and you make use of it (or even your friend, sister and grandmother). It doesn't matter whether you just use it for fun or run your multi-million euro business with it. Also, if you install it on your work PC at some large company, this is still personal use. However, if you are an administrator and want to deploy it to the 500 desktops in your company, this would no longer qualify as personal use.

Comment: Josh Kelley, Pax: You're totally right, I misremembered the license.

Answer (score 8):

Everyone seems to be suggesting VirtualBox but, in my opinion, you can't beat VMWare at the virtualization game.

I would get a copy of VMWare Player (it's free for non-commercial use and you'd be hard pressed to find one cheaper than that), then use this web site [here](http://www.easyvmx.com/easyvmx.shtml) to create yourself a virtual machine to whatever specification you need.

I run heaps of images under XP (and one XP image under Debian) and it really is easy to set up. Early editions of the Linux VMWare required you to re-configure the software whenever the kernel changed but this is now an automatic process.

Comment: Does VMware Player do snapshots?

Comment: Yes, by shutting down the VM and copying the whole directory to somewhere else :-) Actually, that's how we do it for our automated testing. The whole VM is copied in and then started, where the test program all start up automatically and finally FTP results through to a central server before shutting down.

Comment: VMware Player is only free for "personal non-commercial use".

Comment: @emddudley, perhaps you could point out the relevant section of the licence agreement. I see nothing in there that supports this. Although the web page states personal use, that doesn't necessarily mean non-commercial. See comments in the accepted answer.

Comment: The [VMware Player FAQ](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html) states that _VMware Player is free for personal non-commercial use. VMware Player is available for commercial use as part of VMware Fusion Professional._ `EULA.rtf` in the VMware Player installation directory says _SOFTWARE-SPECIFIC TERMS AND CONDITIONS ... VMware Player is intended for your own personal non-commercial use only.  Player may only be used commercially or be re-distributed with written agreement from VMware._

Answer (score 3):

Free emulator for Linux:

**QEmu and KVM**

http://www.qemu.org/

Best I have used.

Answer (score 2):

We're using Xen paravirtualization, and it's working very well.  It's the same technology used by Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) to run your virtual machine images on their physical hosts.  It only costs you 0.5-3.0% of your CPU cycles too.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are your needs?

I would try [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) which uses VirtualBox. It makes it really easy and quick to create and destroy boxes as you need them.

I've found it to be really amazing for getting a new clean development environment up and running. Once you get it going it makes switching, testing, creating, sharing and trashing development environments real easy.

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86
>   virtualization product for enterprise
>   as well as home use. Not only is
>   VirtualBox an extremely feature rich,
>   high performance product for
>   enterprise customers, it is also the
>   only professional solution that is
>   freely available as Open Source
>   Software under the terms of the GNU
>   General Public License (GPL).

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has been well-answered already, but I'd like to add a couple of notes about VirtualBox: (1) In my experience, it is much faster than VMware when running as a Linux host, and (2) the snapshot features have been *greatly* improved in recent versions (the comprehensive snapshot functionality is what kept me in VMware for a long time.)

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.com) is a great virtual machine solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of VirtualBox as well. The OSE is free and runs really well.

VMWare is nice because it's incredibly robust, especially the server edition. With the server edition, you can run all off your VM's of one machine and access them at any time by browsing to VMWare's web GUI. This is a nice feature that I've used time and time again.

I would say that if you're doing just testing/playing around, I'd go with VirtualBox over VMWare.

Comment: "I would say that if you're doing just testing/playing around, I'd go with VirtualBox over VMWare." - why (just curious)?

Comment: It was built for a more personal use where as VMWare deals with both personal and enterprise-level virtualizaion solutions. This is not to say that VMWare won't do what you need to it to if you're just messing around but it takes more room and RAM.